# How to connect Next.js to Database?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an application "like" Samsung Health that will use massively queries on a Database.

I would like to know if is better create a custom server made in Node.js (using Express.js) rather than use the integrated one in Next. On Next documentation seems to be some differences.

Where I can find other documentation? On Next documentation I didn't find anything that tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Anyway (imo) it's better to have a Node server detached of Next (even if its on the same server) because it will be easier to scale. Moreover you still can use NextJs functionalities like SSR, ISR etc You just query your api and not directly your database

Comment: Thanks, do you know some documentation or examples that i can use?

Comment: Depends on what you want.. Possibilities are literally endless, you need to be more specific please

Comment: Some example that show how to connect Next.js to Node.js (Express.js).

Comment: I mean, you can use normal fetches from nextjs to your node api, from the body of your pages functions or in the nextjs methods like getserversideprops etc.. Do you know you to fetch ?

Comment: Ok thanks, I m new with this thing. I m going to read about.

Comment: I have a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75502931/how-to-securely-connect-to-a-database-in-next-js-app-using-prisma-and-mysql-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. I had to use fetch function and pay attention with the promise. I had to take the body of the post request and tranform it into json file. Obviously it's necessary that both backend and frontend are currently running.